# Convergence of derivative in $L^1(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $F(x)$ be a distribution function over $\mathbb{R}$ with positive derivative at origin $f(0)$. Let $Q$ be a measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Can we have following results under some conditions, say $\int{|x|dQ(X)}<\infty$
$$\int{\left|\frac{F(tx)-F(0)}{t}-f(0)x\right|dQ(x)}\rightarrow 0$$.

Can we also have some kind of uniformly convergence,

$$\sup_{|t|\leq c}\int{\left|\frac{F(tx)-F(0)}{t}-f(0)x\right|dQ(x)}\rightarrow 0$$ for some positive constant $c$.